# FFmpeg blur filter not working at all

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to blur out the video using FFMPEG by following there documentation, but it is not working at all, all it do moves the few frames forward (8 sec video became 10 sec video and so blank screen is shown for 2 seconds at the start)

Command used is

```
ffmpeg -i demo2.flv.mp4 -vf "boxblur=2:1" demo2.mp4
```

Complete output of the command is below

```
ffmpeg version 0.10.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 16 2012 13:52:24 with gcc 4.4.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-libvpx --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'demo2.flv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 616 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 481 kb/s, 1000.35 fps, 1 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 36 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : 
File 'demo2.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
w:640 h:360 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_param:
[boxblur @ 0x2c3af00] luma_radius:2 luma_power:1 chroma_radius:2 chroma_power:1 alpha_radius:2 alpha_power:1 w:640 chroma_w:320 h:360 chroma_h:180
[libx264 @ 0x2c5f4c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x2c5f4c0] profile High, level 2.2
[libx264 @ 0x2c5f4c0] 264 - core 125 r2200 999b753 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'demo2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (![0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x360, q=-1--1, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (@[0][0][0] / 0x0040), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : 
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libfaac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Segmentation fault? Have you tried installing / compiling the latest version already? 10.2 is a little outdated.

Comment: not yet, i will try it

Comment: @Kashif Ahmed Any luck? I'd be curious if recent ffmpeg from Git also seg faults with your input and command.

Comment: Today, i have updated to latest ffmpeg version, and no luck :(

Comment: It is strange that earlier 8 sec video was becoming 10 sec and now it becomes 12 sec video now, only difference is now empty frames are at the end of video, so after 8 sec video gets stuck for 4 sec and then ends, also i think blur is working but now the problem is video becomes too blocky and it seems a lot of frames are dropped from video and now video frame per sec became to 1 frame per sec, which too low quality and it is not acceptable at all also tried to set the bit rate but not much improvement :(

Comment: Seems like you're actually getting an output file now. Does this mean you are no longer experiencing a seg fault? If you are still getting a seg fault, could you test other input files? If this is the only file that seg faults can you provide the file?

Comment: yes, now seg fault error is resolved, now only problem is am not getting desired output, mainly video fps drops very low and output video time increased :(